# isNothing throws an exception when parsing JSON file

Tags: json, exception, haskell, aeson

I've got the following functions to decode JSON files using the `Data.Aeson` library:

```
data SearchResult = SearchResult {
  items :: [Item]
} deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON SearchResult where
  parseJSON :: Value -> Parser SearchResult
  parseJSON (Object v) = SearchResult <$>
    parseJSON (fromJust $ HM.lookup "items" v)
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data Item = Item {
  volumeInfo :: VolumeInfo
} deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Item where
  parseJSON :: Value -> Parser Item
  parseJSON (Object v) = Item <$>
    parseJSON (fromJust $ HM.lookup "volumeInfo" v)
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data VolumeInfo = VolumeInfo {
  title :: String,
  authors :: [String],
  publisher :: String,
  publishedDate :: String,
  industryIdentifiers :: [IndustryIdentifier],
  pageCount :: Int,
  categories :: [String]
} deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON VolumeInfo where
  parseJSON :: Value -> Parser VolumeInfo
  parseJSON (Object v) = VolumeInfo <$>
    v .: "title" <*>
    v .: "authors" <*>
    v .: "publisher" <*>
    v .: "publishedDate" <*>
    parseJSON (fromJust $ HM.lookup "industryIdentifiers" v) <*>
    v .: "pageCount" <*>
    v .: "categories"
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data IndustryIdentifier = IndustryIdentifier {
  identifierType :: String,
  identifier :: String
} deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON IndustryIdentifier where
  parseJSON :: Value -> Parser IndustryIdentifier
  parseJSON (Object v) = IndustryIdentifier <$>
    v .: "type" <*>
    v .: "identifier"
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

And this function:

```
getBook content = do
  putStrLn (Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.unpack content)
  let searchResult = decode content :: Maybe SearchResult
  print (isNothing searchResult)
  print searchResult
```

The function `getBook` works with many JSON files. Here's an example:

```
False
Just (SearchResult {items = [Item {volumeInfo = VolumeInfo {title = "A Memoir of Jane Austen", authors = ["James Edward Austen-Leigh","Jane Austen, James Austen-Leigh"], publisher = "Wordsworth Editions", publishedDate = "2007", industryIdentifiers = [IndustryIdentifier {identifierType = "ISBN_10", identifier = "1840225602"},IndustryIdentifier {identifierType = "ISBN_13", identifier = "9781840225600"}], pageCount = 256, categories = ["Novelists, English"]}}]})
```

The JSON content was successfully decoded, and therefore `isNothing` returns `False` in the first line, followed by the decoded content. If I run the function again with [this JSON file](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=inauthor:jane%20austen&printType=books&maxResults=1&startIndex=1) as `content`, I get the following output:

```
True
Nothing
```

The file couldn't be decoded (as there is no field `categories` on the JSON file), and so `isNothing` returns `True`, and `Nothing` is printed on screen. Now the problem is when I run it with [this JSON file](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=inauthor:jane%20austen&printType=books&maxResults=1&startIndex=2) as `content`. I get this:

```
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

An exception is thrown when `print (isNothing searchResult)` is executed, and I don't understand why `True` isn't returned like in the previous example (because in this case there is no field `industryIdentifiers`, for example). What am I missing or doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I found out the problem happens every time the JSON file doesn't include the field `industryIdentifiers`. It fails in this line:

```
parseJSON (fromJust $ HM.lookup "industryIdentifiers" v) <*>
```

Comment: How do you generate the `content` you feed to getBook? If you use `parseJSON` then the `fromJust` exception can come from one of the instances you have declared as they use this unsafe function heavily.

Comment: I'm retrieving the content directly from the webpages I mentioned using  `simpleHttp` from the `Network.HTTP.Conduit` library, as a `ByteString` (`Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.ByteString`). The function `fromJust` is only used in the parsing Aeson functions I included in the beginning of the post.

Comment: That's my point: I'd guess that the `fromJust`s used in the parsing phase fail at some point (is `decode` basically using `parseJSON`?).

Comment: Don't use `fromJust` in real code. `isNothing` isn't much use either. Use pattern matching or `fromMaybe` or `maybe` and you won't have these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The github package defines a convenience operator to define array fields:

```
-- | A slightly more generic version of Aeson's @(.:?)@, using `mzero' instead
-- of `Nothing'.
(.:<) :: (FromJSON a) => Object -> T.Text -> Parser [a]
obj .:< key = case Map.lookup key obj of
                   Nothing -> pure mzero
                   Just v  -> parseJSON v
```

(here `Map` is an alias for `Data.HashMap.Lazy`)

Then the `FromJSON` instance of VolumeInfo would be defined like this:

```
instance FromJSON VolumeInfo
  v .: "title" <*>
  ...
  v .:< "industryIdentifiers" <*>
  ...
```